# Elegant way to write when inside a for loop?

Tags: raku

I can write something like this (`elem` here is an `XML::Element` but it doesn't really matter):

```
for $elem.nodes {
    when XML::Element { ... }
    when XML::Text { ... }
    ...
    default { note qq{Ignoring unknown XML node "$_".} }
}
```

which looks nice, but doesn't give me a readable name for `$_` inside the code using it, which is why I'd prefer to write this:

```
for $elem.nodes -> $child {
    when XML::Element { ... }
    when XML::Text { ... }
    ...
    default { note qq{Ignoring unknown XML node "$child".} }
}
```

but this doesn't work because now `$_` isn't set, and so I actually need to write

```
for $elem.nodes -> $child {
    given $child {
        when XML::Element { ... }
        when XML::Text { ... }
        ...
        default { note qq{Ignoring unknown XML node "$child".} }
    }
}
```

which is a bit redundant and adds an extra level of indentation.

It's definitely not the end of the world, but am I missing some simple way to have both a readable variable name and avoid `given`?

Comment: I dream of a "forgiven"... who knows maybe some day...

Comment: Is smartmatching elegant enough? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can bind the variable above the `when` statements, it's a little uglier but it does the job.

```
for $elem.nodes {
    my $child = $_;
    when XML::Element { say 'I am XML!' }
    when XML::Text { say 'I am text!' }
    default { say "I am default: $child" }
}
```

**Edit**: In Raku I think it is perfectly reasonable to stick to using `$_` seeing as the idea of `$_` has been around for quite some time.

Comment: should this be ```$child := $_;```?

Comment: @p6steve it can be, it shouldn't make a difference in this case though.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is indeed the most reasonable answer, I just hoped there might be some magic way to bind both `$child` and `$_` to the loop value at the same time, somehow -- but if there is none, this is the most clear and concise way to do what I want.

Answer (score 8):

```
for @a -> $x { { 
    when 2 { say "$x ... a" }
    when 4 { say "$x ... b" }
} given $x }
```

naughty double curlies and a post-given?

Comment: my only defence of this shameless use of double curlies is JavaScript ```thing(function() { ... });``` style code

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it's nice to know that it works, but I wouldn't want to defend writing this in a code review...

Answer (score 1):

***Smartmatching the `when` condition(s):***

```perl
my @a = <cat rabbit 2 dog>;
say @a;
say "____\n";

for @a -> $x { 
    when $x ~~ 2 { say "$x ... a" };
    when $x ~~ 4 { say "$x ... b" };
    #default { say $_ if $x.defined; }; #uncomment to catch fall-through;
} ;
```

Returns:

```perl
[cat rabbit 2 dog]
____

2 ... a
```

*Note: `default` above returns `(Any)` for any fall-through, which tells us that `$_` is unset. You can change `default` to something more useful like:*

`default { say "$x is default" if $x.defined };`

---

---

Longer Example:

```bash
% cat ~/exemel_text.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <file>text1</file>
  <file>text2</file>
  <file>text3</file>
  <file>text4</file>
</root>
% raku -MXML -e 'my $mydocument=open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str); 
                 my @array = $mydocument.root.nodes[1,3,5,7...*]; #odd elements only
                 for @array -> $scalar { 
                     when $scalar ~~ XML::Element {say "$scalar is an XML::Element!"}; 
                     when $scalar ~~ XML::Node    {say "$scalar is an XML::Node!"}; 
                     default { say $_ if $scalar.defined };
                 };' ~/exemel_text.xml
<file>text1</file> is an XML::Element!
<file>text2</file> is an XML::Element!
<file>text3</file> is an XML::Element!
<file>text4</file> is an XML::Element!
```

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML

Comment: This is also nice, thanks, although I'm not sure if it's better to repeat `$var ~~` in every line or just do `$var = $_` once, as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75187143/15275).

Comment: Thx! I think `given` serves to topicalize each `when` statement, which you can circumvent by an explicit smartmatch. So you can do a `for`/`when` loop without _too_ much inconvenience.

Comment: FYI, if you have any further interest in manipulating `XML` in Raku, please peruse this repo (any comments/suggestions appreciated!): https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind when I have to do something with XML the next time (hopefully not too soon :-)